# Slick proof that Coxeter groups $H_3$ and $H_4$ are finite?

Tags: finite-groups, polyhedra, coxeter-groups

I'm planning to teach a course on reflection/Coxeter groups next Fall, and have started outlining the first days, which will presumably be the classification of finite reflection groups. Here is an issue I've run into.

At the end of the classification, one has shown that every finite reflection group is generated by reflections in a set of linearly independent vectors $\alpha_i$ (the simple roots) which I'll normalize to have length $1$, and has described all possible Gram matrices $( \langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle)$. One then wants to show that all the Gram matrices on the list actually occur.

Given a positive definite Gram matrix $G$, one can always find linearly independent vectors $\alpha_i$ and one can consider the group $W$ generated by reflections in them. But it is not clear that $W$ is finite.

In all but two cases, $W$ is crystallographic, meaning that it preserves a lattice. It is easy to show that a subgroup of $O(n)$ preserving a rank $n$ lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite.

The remaining cases are the dihedral groups $I_2^n$, and the groups $H_3$ and $H_4$ (symmetry groups of the icoshaedron and the [600-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell), respectively). I am willing to treat it as obvious that the dihedral groups are finite, and maybe I'm willing to bring in an icosahedron in place of a proof, but I'd rather not just rely on brute force computation to assert that $H_4$ is finite.

> For the groups $H_3$ and $H_4$, is there a quick way to see that the group generated by these reflections is finite?

The route which I would most like to take is to prove the following lemma. I know this result is true, and I'll want it later in the course, but I don't know of a proof which can be given before I have built up any tools

> **Lemma** Let $\alpha_1$, ... $\alpha_n$ be unit vectors in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that each $\langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle$ is
>   of the form $-\cos  \tfrac{\pi}{m_{ij}}$ for $i \neq j$. Let $W$ be
>   the group generated by the reflections in the $\alpha_i$, and let
>   $\Phi = W \cdot \{ \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \}$. Then every vector
>   in $\Phi$ is either a positive linear combination of the $\alpha_i$ or
>   a negative linear combination of the $\alpha_i$.

If I can prove this, I can establish the result as follows: Take the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ and cut it along each of the hyperplanes $\beta^{\perp}$ for $\beta \in \Phi$. $W$ acts on the connected components of the sliced sphere. Let $D$ be the region $S^{n-1} \cap \{ \omega : \langle \alpha_i, \omega \rangle > 0  \}$. The hypothesis implies that $D$ is one of the connected components, and it has positive $(n-1)$-dimensional volume. Since $\mathrm{Vol}(S^{n-1}) < \infty$, the $W$-orbit of $D$ must be finite, and it is easy to show that the stabilizer of $D$ is trivial. But I don't know if I can prove this lemma with no tools.

Comment: Are you planning to prove the fundamental domain theorem for reflection groups? If you do (which is how you prove their linearity) then finiteness for $H_3, H_4$ easily follows.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Not sure exactly which phrasing you consider as "the fundamental domain theorem". If you mean that the region $D$ described above (or by some similar definition) is a fundamental domain, certainly I will eventually. What I need for this purpose is half of that, that $D \cap w D = \emptyset$ for $w \neq e$. But the question is how easy it is to get there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by linearity -- a reflection group is linear by definition. Once we have abstract Coxeter groups, linearity is a key issue, but I am talking about classifying finite reflection groups.

Comment: I'd still be glad to hear answers to this, but I have decided that Moishe is right -- the fundamental domain theorem is easy enough to prove right at the start and that is the route I should take.

Comment: I was thinking about (finitely generated) Coxeter groups defined via a Coxeter system. Then, after establishing the fundamental domain theorem, in one swoop you prove linearity of Coxeter groups and finiteness of Coxeter groups of elliptic type.

Comment: By a Coxeter system I mean the standard presentation.

Comment: I see. I am pretty confident I want to first define reflection groups and work with them for a while before defining Coxeter groups via presentations. But I think I can make a schedule work which is Examples of Reflection Groups, Classification of Reflection Groups (without proving the exceptional groups exist), Proof of fundamental domain theorem (at which point, it follows that the exceptional groups do exist.)

Comment: This isn't a very practical suggestion (and certainly too late to be of use!) but you could think of H3 and H4 as the subgroups of D6 and E8 respectively by Muhlher's theorem on admissible partitions (see [Coxeter Groups in Coxeter Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-geometries-and-combinatorics/coxeter-groups-in-coxeter-groups/9D39282834D497FEC0B00C73E3D2EC31)). In fact that whole paper offers a nice 'scenic route' to determining the finite irreducible Coxeter Groups.